# What Digital Asset Management software supports multi-user collaborative catalog management?

Tags: photo-editing, file-management, software-recommendation

How can a newspaper group with multiple photographers (15+) that, all-together, take and rate pictures from 3 or 4 events daily, manage a photo catalog?

I've heard of Digital Asset Management before, but I'm looking for a solution that runs a server on a local network and has client software that individual computers can access at the same time.

The ability to edit photos in Photoshop and use photos (as links) in InDesign is crucial.

Comment: Sounds like a question for one of our computing/software oriented sites. Even though the task at hand is about photography, the solution is in softwares, databases, digital access, etc.

Comment: In order to answer, you must tell us: 1. How many photos/day come totally/from each photographer? 300, 500, 1000? 2. What platforms do you need? Windows? Linux, MacOSX? 3. Do you need only Rate & Color or also Keywording? 4. What experience do your team have with computers, cataloging and DAM? 5. Do you have the possibility to test (iow put a certain program test it for 3 weeks and if it's ok keep it)?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the below solutions:

- [Daminion Server](http://daminion.net)
- Portolfio Server
- Canto Cumulus
- FotoWare FotoStation
- Apple Final CutServer (Mac based, abandoned by Apple)

I work at Daminion Software. So I can provide more info about Daminion Server, but I've also listed other products above so you can save your search time and compare products in my list.

There are a lot of standalone digital asset management solutions, but they are not for multi-user usage scenario. All the above products are true multi-user solutions so can runs a server part of your DAM on your server PC and then access to your centralized image and document repository using client programs that will be installed on local computers in your local network.

Daminion and Portfolio are aimed at small and medium size businesses.

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain why each of these might be a good fit? We prefer answers that give content, not just a straight list.

Comment: * from $999 USD

Comment: Philip, I've expanded my answer a bit. I would describe Daminion in details but it might be considered as an advertizement, so I tried to keep my post neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Another option which would work well for your scenario is [DBGallery](http://www.dbgallery.com), a solution for which I am part of the product team.  It is a multi-user photo organization system which runs across a local area network.  Links from InDesign work because it stores links to the original files rather than storing the images in the database.  To edit the file in hotoshop, simply press Ctrl-D once the image is found and the software passes the file path to Photoshop for editing (or whichever is set as the default image editor).  Photos may be rated from 1 to 5 stars.